# WTForms: set value when rendering

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

There is probably a better way to do this but I am trying to use a hidden form to define buttons in Flask using WTForms. When I try to set the values, it appears as though the fields are being generated twice. Once with the default value of "" and again with the value set in the template. Ultimately what is past back during the post is null values for both variables.

What I am trying to do is set the value on each instantiation to different values based on the button that is assigned which means it has to be done in the template.

Here is what I have:

Form defined in the flask app:

```
class refreshInstances(Form):
    type = HiddenField('type')
    value = HiddenField('value')


def instances():
  form = refreshInstances()
   return render_template('instances.html', form=form)
```

Subset of template instances.html:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" role="form" id="updall">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.type(value='res_id') }}
            {{ form.value(value='12345') }}
</form>
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-block' type='submit' form='updall'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Update All</button>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" role="form" id="updall">
 <div>
  <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1428">
  <input id="type" name="type" type="hidden" value="">
  <input id="value" name="value" type="hidden" value="">
 </div>
 <input id="type" name="type" type="hidden" value="res_id">
 <input id="value" name="value" type="hidden" value="cjohnson">
</form>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="submit" form="updall"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Update All</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to `type` and `value` to render twice in the one form?  If not, the problem is that `form.hidden_tag()` renders all hidden fields, including `csrf_token`, `type`, and `value`.  Assuming you are using csrf_token (a good idea unless you have a good reason not to), replace `form.hidden_tag()` with `form.csrf_token()`:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" role="form" id="updall">
            {{ form.csrf_token()         }}
            {{ form.type(value='res_id') }}
            {{ form.value(value='12345') }}
</form>
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-block' type='submit' form='updall'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Update All</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can solve your problem.
You should adapt it as you need.

```
def instances():
    form = refreshInstances()
    form.type.default = 123
    form.value.default = 456
    form.process()
    return render_template('instances.html', form=form)

<form class="form" method="POST" role="form" id="updall">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.type }}
    {{ form.value }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE

```
 `<form class="form" method="POST" role="form" id="updall">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                {{ form.type(value='res_id') }}
                {{ form.value(value='12345') }} </form>`
```

to

```
<form class="form" method="POST" role="form" id="updall">
            {{ form.type(value='res_id') }}
            {{ form.value(value='12345') }}
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why does this work? Please elaborate.

Comment: When jinja does {{ form.hidden_tag() }} it loads all the HiddenFields from "class/object" without "attributes" as value; These are the ones it sends to the server; But when you change {{ form.hidden_tag() }} at the end, it first loads the HiddenFields one by one.
1: {{ form.type(value='res_id') }}
 ( class/object->puts "attributes"->renders html)...
then it loads all empty HiddenFields with {{ form. hidden_tag() }} (class >render html), but now the first HiddenFields are sent with their "values", I guess because they are loaded first.
So in the end the HiddenFields are duplicated.